# Is possible to get dictionary of values with linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have solution in my mind, but I am convinced that there must be better solution for the problem.

Lets think I have two tables - User (n..n) Group. In my app I wish to get list of Users, each with all his Groups. In SQL I can achieve similar result with:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) u.Name, g.Name
FROM [User] u
join [GroupUser] gu on u.Id = gu.UserId
join [Group] g on gu.GroupId = g.Id
```

In the code I am able to write something like this (please, don't judge the correctness, it's just for illustration):

```
var result = new Dictionary<Model.User, List<Model.Group>>();
List<string> names = request.Names;
var query = this.dbContext.Set<Model.User>().AsQueryable();

query = from user in query
where names.Contains(user.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
select user;

foreach(var user in await query.ToListAsync())
{
    var groupQuery = 
        from g in this.dbContext.Set<Model.Group>()
        join gu in this.dbContext.Set<Model.GroupUser>() on g.Id equals gu.GroupId
        join u in this.dbContext.Set<Model.User>() on gu.UserId equals u.Id
        where u.Name.Equals(user.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        select g;

    result.Add(user, await groupQuery.ToListAsync())
}
```

My question is -- is possible to achieve something like this with single linq query? Or do I really need to enumerate all the Users and fire new query for each of them? This code looks very resource demanding. It is quite simple, only one cycle, but it contains `Users.Count+1` query evaluations.

Thanks in advance for hints.

Comment: See `ToDictionary` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: According to `dbContext.Set` call, this should be EF (6? Core?). In both cases you should have/use a collection navigation property and no dictionary / special query is needed.

Comment: s. `.ToLookup()`

Comment: Your code has a LINQ statement that does nothing because it isn't assigned to anything. Did you really intend to get all `Users` and their `Groups`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using LINQ to SQL, you can combine the queries:

```
var requestedUsers = from user in query
                     where names.Contains(user.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                     select user;

var result = (from u in requestedUsers
              join gu in this.dbContext.Set<Model.User>() on u.UserId equals gu.Id
              join g in this.dbContext.Set<Model.Group>() on gu.UserId equals g.Id into gj
              select new { u, gj })
              .ToDictionary(ugj => ugj.u, ugj => ugj.gj.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an entity like the following:

```
public class User
{
    // other properties

    public virtual List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

You can query both with an `Include`:

```
var users = dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.Groups)
                .Where(u => names.Contains(u.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```